# Updating facebook status using PHP cURL

Tags: php, facebook, curl, status

I was trying to update the status using PHP cURL script ,when I run the script facbook blocks it update the status by saying an unrecognized device trying to update your status ,after which I save the device with some name .But when I again run the script it shows the same notification and doesn't update the status.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not using the API and are triggering some security systems.
Use the [API](http://developers.facebook.com) instead.

Comment: I have seen ,we can update the status using graph API of facebook .I am not sure, but I think going by that way I will be needing access token for a user and for that I have to make an facebook application .

Comment: That's correct - attempting to use a username/password and automate logins is expressly against Facebook's policies and will almost certainly result in the account being automatically locked